# Uniform continuity of a subset of $R$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $A \subset R$ and $f:A\to R$ be given by $f(x) = x^2$. Then $f$ is uniformly continuous if

1. $A$ is bounded subset of $R$.
2. $A$ is dense subset of $R$.
3. $A$ is unbounded and connected subset of $R$.
4. $A$ is unbounded and open subset of $R$.

I think that some information is missing from this question.

Suppose $A =\{ 1,2,3\}$ then one can not speak of uniform continuity on $A$. This is because limit and continuity at a point $x$ is always defined on a neighborhood of that point. 
So (1) fails.

Take $A = R$ then (2), (3) and (4) fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the restriction of a uniformly continuous function is uniformly continuous.

Assuming that $A$ is bounded, then there exists $M>0$ such that $A\subseteq [-M,M]$. Notice that $g:[-M,M]\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $g(x):=x^2$ is continuous on a compact subset and, in turn, is uniformly continuous. Notice that $g|_A=f$ and hence, $f$ is a uniformly continuous function.

So, (1) holds. I agree that (2), (3), and (4) all fail since, like you mentioned, letting $A=\mathbb{R}$ gives a counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

The right answer is 1.

It makes perfect sense to define continuity and uniform continuity in isolated point. In particular *uniform continuity* is never defined by means of limit. It is defined as:
$$
\forall \varepsilon>0\quad \exists \delta>0 \colon |x-y|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon.
$$
which makes perfect sense whatever is the domain of $f$.

Most text don't define limits in isolated point, but they surely define continuity on isolated point by saying that a function is continuous *by definition* in such points. As a matter of fact if you take the definition of continuity given as:
$$
  \lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)
$$
and plug in the definition of limit, you get:
$$
\forall \epsilon>0\quad \exists\delta>0\colon 0<|x-x_0|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)| < \varepsilon
$$
which makes perfect sense also in isolated point (and is always true in such points). Notice also that you can remove the condition $0<|x-x_0|$ since for $x=x_0$ the statement is anyway true.

Comment: What do you mean by saying that a uniformly continuous function need not have a limit? This is an incorrect assertion. If limit exists at a point, then with an additional property that the limit is equal to its functional value, we can talk about continuity. Now every uniformly continuous function is continuous. Do you not think that if $\epsilon$ is not dependent on $x$ in the definition of continuity , you can easily get your definition of uniform continuity?

Comment: I was just thinking about the definitions, so I posted...

Comment: Removal does not happen by choice, there has to be justification!

Comment: I'm saying that you don't need the *concept* of limit to define *continuity* nor *uniform continuity*. As a matter of fact every function defined on $\{1,2,3\}$ is *uniformly continuous*.

Comment: No you do... However, now I get why the function is uniformly continuous {1,2,3}. If you do not have a neighborhood to begin with one can vacuously conclude on the interval [1,1] to be true by taking the empty neighbourhood. It is taken to be true by default. It is the same with limit or continuity!